# Xcode Renaming Class's and XIB ERRORS?

Tags: xcode, xib, semantics, naming

Ive been cleaning up my code abit and started renaming some .h and .m files which link to xib files. I did this to my main view controller and have no got about 20 Semantic Issues all linking to the xib i assume i have no clue what the correct procedure is to fix this issue. 
Thanks in advance for your help!!

Here is the screen shot : 
[image]

Comment: whole project or some classes?

Comment: i have renamed the whole project but the errors are within the .m of the class ive changed

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

By seeing the error in screen shot do this **Long and difficult task** add the following in your current class.

```
#import "BTViewController.h"
```

---

Instead of doing manually you should refactor as :

Select the class name.
[image]

Chose Refactor from menu, and follow the steps.

[image]

Comment: what is OBJECTNAME? you haven't declared it.

Comment: @mdcuk: 1st. You should show the screen shot in question, not in answer. 2nd. In the screen shot, interface file is not recognized, fix that bug.

Comment: email sent did you get it?

Comment: Thanks thats cleared all the errors, stupid mistake. Its crashing when i run the app now though?

Comment: then check for other reasons

Comment: As you have said you changed classnames, check for all the xib's controls class name. you must have missed

Comment: Yeah its defiantly something to do with the name change cause this is the error.which is stating previous names: 2013-04-03 13:07:29.610 BoatTracker[24645:c07] Unknown class HelloThereAppDelegate in Interface Builder file.
2013-04-03 13:07:29.611 BoatTracker[24645:c07] Unknown class HelloThereViewController in Interface Builder file.
2013-04-03 13:07:29.613 BoatTracker[24645:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICustomObject 0x843c420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewController.'